# How to make a click event in android graph

Tags: android

I just implemented graph in my application using View, that just displays the rating for a particular month.I need to have a button there for showing the previous month's rating.My class doesn't extend Activity.So i am not able to use intent here.

This is the page i have..[image]

How can i achieve this ?.Any help will be greatly appreciated !!